# Predicate Logic and Calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Question of the week came up in my schools logic club but there is not much information to it. Here is the question:

Show that

$$
\exists x\,[R(x)\wedge \lnot Q(x)],\ \forall x\,[P(x)\to Q(x)],\, \forall x[R(x)\to(P(x)\vee S(x))] \models \exists x\,[R(x)\wedge S(x)]
$$

Describe in details all your work

Now I know that it does not want us to use formal deduction, so what method do they want us to use then? Formal Deduction is the only way I am familiar with at the moment but apparently that has been ruled out as a possible method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $\exists x(Rx\land\neg Qx)$ and instantiate, i.e. infer $(Ra\land\neg Qa)$.

Since $\forall x(Px\to Qx)$, we have $Pa\to Qa$. But since $\neg Qa$, then necessarily $\neg Pa$.

Finally, $\forall x(Rx\to(Px\lor Sx))$ gives $Ra\to (Pa\lor Sa)$. And since $Ra$ and $\neg Pa$, then necessarily $Sa$.

$$Ra\land\neg Qa\land\neg Pa\land Sa\to\exists x(Rx\land Sx)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that what the question asks to have proved is not a "$\vdash$" statement, but a "$\vDash$" statement -- thus, you're being asked to prove that any structure that satisfies the three premises will also satisfy $\exists x(R(x)\land S(x))$.

One way to do this would indeed be to present a formal proof of the "$\vdash$" entailment, and then appeal to some known result that the proof system you're using is *sound*. But apparently that's not what you're supposed to do.

The other option is to reason directly (and informally, that is, in everyday mathematical style) about $\vDash$, and what it means for the various formulas to be satisfied in a structure:

> Given a structure $(\mathfrak M,P_{\mathfrak M},Q_{\mathfrak M}, R_{\mathfrak M},S_{\mathfrak M})$ which satisfies such-and-such we need to find an $x\in\mathfrak M$ such that $x\in R_{\mathfrak M}$ and $x\in S_{\mathfrak M}$. Because $\mathfrak M\vDash \exists x(R(x)\land\neg Q(x)$ we know that $\mathfrak M$ contains an $x$ such that $x\in R_{\mathfrak M}$ and $x\notin Q_{\mathfrak M}$. *(And so forth ...)*